# Outlook Rules for moving incoming emails sent to a specific BCC Distribution List

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, rules, email-filter

I am part of many Distribution Lists (DLs), and I have distinct rules for them. Those rules work fine when the DL is in To or Cc. However, in certain circumstances, Senders put the DL in BCC, and some recipients in To or Cc. I am wondering how could I enable the existing rules for such emails ?

The simultaneous conditions would be:

- My name is not in To, Cc, or Bcc
- There are recipients in To or Cc (but not me!)
- A *certain* DL is in Bcc

Outlook 365, if this detail makes any difference.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, BCC doesnt show the recipient by design and there is no existed rule for it. Workarounds like yours or using Exception conditions in Outlook rules would be a little help. Please check: [How to create Rule for BCC Mails to Move Correct Folders?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/184954/how-to-create-rule-for-bcc-mails-to-move-correct-f.html)